# Functions to Scheme and Schemes to Functions SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

A friend asked me this earlier and I wasn't sure how to answer this, he said he got it in an interview.  When partitioning in SQL Server, is there a limit to how many partition schemes you can put on a partition function?  And how many partition functions can you put on a scheme?  Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one partition function per scheme. You can have many schemes all use the same function. Each scheme must have an associated filegroup capable of holding the partitions associated with the partition function.

There limit for how many partition schemes can use a partition function lies in the capability of the filegroup to hold all of the partitions.

The limit for how many partition functions can be used in one scheme is 1.

The limit for how many partition functions can be created is listed below.

---

*SQL Server 2008*

You can have 1000 partition functions in SQL Server 2008

`n: "Specifies the number of values supplied by boundary_value, not to exceed 999."`
-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187802(v=sql.100).aspx

---

*SQL Server 2012*

You can have 15000 partition functions in SQL Server 2012

`n: "Specifies the number of values supplied by boundary_value, not to exceed 14,999."`
-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187802(v=sql.110).aspx